# How can I count the rows in a table above a Certain Data Point?

Tags: php, sql

I have made a leaderboard for a quiz ordered by their score and I want to show the position of the user. How could I count how many rows are above them in the table in order to determine their position? This code only works when people don't have the same score. If 2 people both have the high score, both will see themselves as number 2.

```
function firstPlace() {
    include 'connection.php';
    $sql="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$_SESSION[email]'";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if(isset($row1[4])) {
            $score=$row1[4];
        }
    }
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$_SESSION[email]'";
    $result2=mysqli_query($connection,$sql2);
    $sql1="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Score >= $score ORDER BY Score DESC";
    $result1=mysqli_query($connection,$sql1);
    $numRows=mysqli_num_rows($result1);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        if($row[5]!="") {
            $src1="photos/".$row[5];
        }
        else {
            $src1='images/profile-pic.png';
        }
        echo "
        <a  class='logo' href='index.php'><img src='$src1' class='bigProfilePic' id='logo' alt='Profile pic'></a>
        <h1>$numRows</h1>
        <h2>$row[1]</h2>
        <h3>$row[4]<span>Kms</span></h3>";
    }
```

Comment: Share some code, show how you extract the data, explain where and when do you want to show the position. If you want to show the position from the start, just add a counter into the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'SELECT count(id) FROM Users WHERE Score > ?';
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $Score );
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Will give you how many users have score higher than $score, you could of course also keep the query open for sql injction as the others if you want to